# TFS automatically includes excluded files

Tags: tfs

This is a weird problem I keep facing. I sometimes find that files that have been excluded in TFS are included and thus each time I check-in, these files that were previously excluded risks getting pushed into the server.
This kind of problem happens most often when I restart my machine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You will need to provide more information. E.g. Visual studio/TFS plugin for eclipse version, directory layout, .tfignore contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you right click on a solution, project, or folder to check-in you are automatically calling "include" on that structure recursively. If you want to permanently exclude those files you can put a .tfignore file in there.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245454.aspx